# Как в c# узнать было ли что либо найдено после выполнения sql запроса?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Выполняю запрос к бд и мне нужно в результат узнать информацию "Было ли что либо найдено в БД или нет" Как это сделать?

Делаю таким образом но понимаю что это не правильно:

```
Guid? ProductId = Guid.Empty;
var foundItemFlag = false;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 t1.ProductId
                                FROM Products t1
                                JOIN Brands t2 ON t2.BrandId = t1.BrandId
                                WHERE t1.Product = @Product AND t2.Brand = @Brand";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", item.Product).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", item.Brand).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ProductId = (Guid)reader["ProductId"];
            }
        }
    }

    if (ProductId != Guid.Empty || ProductId != null)
    {
        foundItemFlag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вероятно, достаточно проверять свойство `reader.HasRows`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это правильный ответ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, спасибо) напишите в ответ, отмечу как правильный

Comment: @AK, точно правильный? Может в данном случае правильнее запускать команду через `ExecuteScalar`? И выкинуть при этом небольшую кучку языковых конструкций :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно проверять свойство [SqlDataReader.HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).